# Charindex returning extra letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return to separate the city and the state names in separate columns but for some reason, I still get the wrong results.

```
SELECT
    LEFT([Location], LEN([Location]) - CHARINDEX('-', [Location])),
    RIGHT([Location], LEN([Location]) - CHARINDEX('-', [Location]))
FROM
    HospitalStaff
```

[image: s]

Comment: Post your sample data as DDL/DML statements, and your expected results as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select left(location, charindex('-', location + '-') - 1),
       stuff(location, 1, charindex('-', location + '-'), '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff7276e7388e5a9ec5f3524b0964a037) is a db<>fiddle.